# Are there link pulses when autonegotiation on ethernet is off (force speed and duplex)?

Tags: ethernet, pulse

I read [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11072/link-pulse-when-autonegotiation-is-off-on-fe-ge-ethernet). Is it correct that there is no link pulse when speed and duplex are forced (autonegotiation turned off)?

Comment: It appears that you are just duplicating a question that perfectly belongs on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ Without adding further details that ask about electronics (hardware layer) parts of the problem, the question, as it stands, is really not a good fit for Stack Exchange. Please consider a significant edit that justifies asking again, without just (nor not even) duplicating the other question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question you referenced is correct... more precisely, it was correct until EEE (Energy Effective Ethernet) was invented.  [EEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Efficient_Ethernet) employs the same fast link pulses to signal the link is up while the phys are in power-saving mode.

In 10BASE-T, FLPs are used to indicate the link is still on while there are no packet transmitted between the stations.

In 1000BASE-T, auto-negotiation is mandatory, you cannot turn it off at all, at least master-slave relation must be resolved from AN.

Also, it is preferable to not turn off AN even if you want to operate on an exact speed and duplex. You must select only that link ability (mode) and then start the AN process.

Therefore, my answer to this question is that the stated assumption is correct in some cases only, not in all.

Comment: umm no, it's normal link pulses that are used to indicate the interface is up on 10BASE-T not fast link pulses.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the speed.

10BASE-T sends "normal link pulses" to indicate that the connection is available. This applies both on links without autonegotiation and links where autonegotiation is completed.

100BASE-TX sends a continuous signal which can be used to detect link status.

1000BAST-T requires autonegotiation (though it can be restricted to only negotiate particular settings)
Autonegotiation uses "fast link pulse bursts" to exchange negotiation information. If the port sees "normal link pulses" it goes into 10BASE-T half duplex mode. Optionally (and in most cases in practice) an autonegotiating port can implement "paralell detection" which places the port in 100BASE-TX half duplex mode if it sees a 100BASE-TX signal.